# Changing link address of menu items index.php to another page in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I am learning Joomla. 
I have a problem to use different pages in joomla.

I created few pages account.php profile.php 
Now I want to change link address index.php to account.php and profile.php of the menu items  I tried to change address link of menu items but always being index.php anyone can help me...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a component that include your pages and then access to your page using standard url format:
option, view, controller, task ...

Here is a good starting point:
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component